# php number_format gives error message

Tags: php, xml

I am using php to parse an XML file, but I get an error message when attempting to display a formatted number:

Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, object given in /home/chesspro/public_html/UNYCL/people-8.php on line 45

```
<?php 
$xml = simplexml_load_file('Rochester_1.xml');

foreach($xml->meet as $item) {

    print '<table class="basic report tableland brown_gradient"><thead>';
    print '<tr><th class="R-align">Board</th><th class="L-align">'.$item->visitor.'</th>';

    $subtotal = 0;
    foreach($item->match as $temp) {$subtotal = $subtotal + $temp->white->score;}
    print "<th>" .number_format($subtotal,1). "</th>";

    $subtotal = 0;
    foreach($item->match as $temp) {$subtotal = $subtotal + $temp->black->score;}
    print "<th>" .number_format($subtotal,1). "</th>";

    print '<th class="L-align">'.$item->home.'</th>';

    print '</tr><tbody>';

    foreach($item->match as $game) {

    print '<tr><td class="R-align">'. $game->board . "</td>";
    print '<td>'. $game->white->player."</td>";

    //Here is error: note that number is sometimes 0
        $X = $game->white->score;
        print '<td>'. number_format($X) ."</td>";

    print '<td>'. $game->black->score."</td>";       
    print '<td class="L-align">'. $game->black->player."</td>";

    print "</tr>";}
print '</table>';}
?>
```

Now can I fix this? I need one point of decimal precision (X.X) although some numbers are integers like "7" which I want to format and display as "7.0" Note that I am using a near current php version 5.3.4

Comment: Does it work when you change it to: `$subtotal = $subtotal + floatval((string)$temp->white->score);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print '<td>'. number_format($X, 1) ."</td>";
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

If this doesn't work try type casting: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting

```
$X = (float)$game->white->score;
print '<td>'. number_format($X) ."</td>";
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Result is at: http://rochesterchesspro.com/UNYCL/people-8.php Thank you both!

Comment: Warning: Floats are dangerous. Ex: Instead of 11, casting to a float may result in 10.999999999999999

Answer (score 1):

It looks a like `$game->white->score` doesn't return float or int.
Try doing like this 
`$X = (float)$game->white->score;
 print '<td>'. number_format($X) ."</td>";`

But number_format() with one parameter will return numbers grouped in thousands, so if you want like 7.0 , better use `print '<td>'. number_format($X,1) ."</td>";`